# Gitkraken revert deleted files

Tags: gitlab, git-submodules, gitkraken

Currently, I am using GitKraken to upload my files to Gitlab. However, there was a submodule that contained all my files for the project - in an attempt to combine the submodule into the main respiratory, I tried deleting it; however, my entire submodule is gone now. When I go into the trash folder of my Mac, I can see the folder except it is named with extra letters and contains files such as Build and Test Index. Is there anyway to get this submodule back?

UPDATE: I tried reverting the files from the trash folder, but it only put the files back into the derived data folder. Not sure how to get the submodule back, it is asking to initialize it by specifying a URL.